# angular2 Observable.throw doesn't work after Observable.timer

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, retrywhen

I'm trying to do a `retrywhen` on a `http.get` for X-times when communication fails.

After the X-times I would like to throw an error that it failed to connect.

If I only do in my `DelayWhen` an `Observable.throw` it directly works fine and returns on the first try.
But if i for the first times return an `Obersvable.timer`, to delay the next to tries for connection afterwards the `Observable.throw` is called but it will not be forwarded to my upper level catch!?

```
public initializeCommunication(): Promise<boolean> {
 return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (r: boolean) => void, reject: (e: 
  Error) => void) => {
 return this.getInternal<DTO>(this.Url, null, 
 'clientidentity')
.retryWhen((errors: Observable<any>) => {
                    // Retry upon communication failure
                    // TODO: Consider only retrying a limited number of 
                    //times and throw an error (call reject)

                    return errors.delayWhen((response: Response) => {
                        retrytrys++;
                        console.log('number of retries   ' + retrytrys);

                        if (retrytrys > 2) {
                            console.log('throw');
                            return Observable.throw(new Error('error!'));
                        }
                        console.log('ret');
                        return Observable.timer(this.RETRY_TIMEOUT);
                    });
                })
                .subscribe()
});
}
```

and this function I'm calling from another service and in that the catch is not called.

```
            myService.initializeCommunication().then((r: boolean) => {

            })
            .catch((error) => { //this is not called }
```

Comment: Your code works fine. What do you mean about 'upper level catch'? Can you update example with it?

Comment: I edit the code snipped with more details. I mean that the catch of my other service is not called even that an error is throw in the `retrywhen`. If i don't return the `Observable.timer` but directly on first run trough the error than the error will be catched!

Comment: Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/VYZhPYoKnLwZcalZHxsf?p=preview) where everything works

Comment: thanks very much it works, yes.